# Theory closed under substructures implies universally axiomatizable

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let ${\cal L}$, ${\cal L'}$ be first order languages.

Let $T'$ be an ${\cal L}'$ theory, and let ${\bf C}$ be the class of all ${\cal L}$ structures which can be expanded to a model of $T'$.

Show that if ${\bf C}$ is closed under taking substructures then ${\bf C}$ is universally axiomatizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the theory $T$ consisting of all universal ${\cal L}$ formulas $\phi$ with $T' \models \phi$.

Suppose ${\frak A} \models T$.  We claim that $T' \cup {\rm Diag}({\frak A})$ is consistent.

If not, there is a formula $\phi(a) \in {\rm Diag}({\frak A})$ such that $T' \vdash \neg \phi(a)$.  But then since $\phi$ is quantifier free, $T' \vdash \forall x \neg \phi(x)$, so $\forall x \neg \phi(x) \in T$, a contradiction since ${\frak A} \models \exists x \phi(x)$.

Let ${\frak C}$ be a model of $T' \cup {\rm Diag}({\frak A})$.  Then ${\frak A}$ embeds into ${\frak C}$.  So ${\frak A} \in {\bf C}$ since ${\bf C}$ is closed under substructures.

Conversely, if ${\frak A} \not \models T$, then clearly we can't have ${\frak A}' \models T'$ for an expansion of ${\frak A}$.

So $T$ is a set of universal axioms for ${\bf C}$.